# How to set ".maxstack" with ILGenerator

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, cil, reflection.emit

How to set the **.maxstack** directive with [ILGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx)?

For instance, a typical setter method has a **.maxstack** of **2**:

```
.maxstack 2         // The evaluation stack has a max size of 2

IL_0000: ldarg.0                  // the current instance (this)
IL_0001: ldarg.1                  // new value
IL_0002: stfld Int32 _someField   // stores the new value on _someField
IL_0007: ret                      // Return to caller
```

It's possible to set metadata with `ILGenerator` because it actually offers [DefineLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.definelabel(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DeclareLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1xffef4(v=vs.110).aspx), so why doesn't it offer a `SetMaxStack(short/int)` method or something similar?

If I can't set this metadata, how does `Reflecion.Emit` determines the size of the stack? Does it set it to the max possible value? Or maybe the stack automatically expands at runtime?

Comment: It doesn't trust you to do it right.  DeclareLocal() always gets it right.

Answer (score 2):

The `ILGenerator` Class will keep track of the stacksize. Have a look at the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/ilgenerator.cs,cfc4df22600be8e8). For example the [UpdateStackSize](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/ilgenerator.cs,a8fada1376960d46) function is involved.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is it isn't setting the max-stack correctly even though your method is very simple, continue reading below.

What might not be obvious from the Metadata at first is, there are two forms of method headers within the CLI: Tiny and Fat headers.

The method header, according to the ECMA-335 (II.25.4.1 Method header type values) comes in two forms: `CorILMethod_TinyFormat` (`0x02`) and `CorILMethod_FatFormat` (`0x03`.)

The tiny format for methods does not allow the specification of max stack.  As it always must be at or below eight (`8`.)

The reason you can't set it is due to what thehennyy mentioned: the IL Builder keeps track of the stack limits for you.

There's a few other restrictions that go beyond your question, but if you're curious you can take a peek at the [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), which spells it all out for you (in very explicit detail, may be NSFW :)