# How to change the .maxstack size of constructor and methods in dynamic assembly

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I want to dynamically create an assembly using the functionality provided `System.Reflection.Emit`. The assembly should be identical to the assembly that results from compiling the following C# code:

```cs
namespace BasicModule
{
   using Prism.Ioc;
   using Prism.Modularity;

   public class BasicModule : IModule
   {
      public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
      {
      }

      public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

The IL code that I'm getting when compiling the above code looks as follows:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit BasicModule.BasicModule
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
       implements [Prism]Prism.Modularity.IModule
{
} // end of class BasicModule.BasicModule


.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       8 (0x8)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  ret
} // end of method BasicModule::.ctor


.method public hidebysig newslot virtual final 
        instance void  OnInitialized(class [Prism]Prism.Ioc.IContainerProvider containerProvider) cil managed
{
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method BasicModule::OnInitialized


.method public hidebysig newslot virtual final 
        instance void  RegisterTypes(class [Prism]Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) cil managed
{
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method BasicModule::RegisterTypes
```

I'm using the following C# class code to generate the assembly dynamically:

```cs
namespace EmitNewAssembly
{
   using Prism.Ioc;
   using Prism.Modularity;
   using System;
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.Reflection;
   using System.Reflection.Emit;

   internal class TestAssemblyCreator
   {
      private const string FileName = "BasicModule.dll";
      private const string ModuleName = "BasicModule";
      private const string ClassName = "BasicModule";

      private const MethodAttributes InterfaceMethodAttributes =
         MethodAttributes.Public |
         MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
         MethodAttributes.NewSlot |
         MethodAttributes.Virtual |
         MethodAttributes.Final;

      private const TypeAttributes ClassAttributes =
         TypeAttributes.Public |
         TypeAttributes.Class |
         TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit;

      public TestAssemblyCreator()
      {
         AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName()
         {
            Name = "TestAssembly",
            Version = new Version(1, 2, 3, 4),
            CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
         };

         var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);

         var typeBuilder = assemblyBuilder
            .DefineDynamicModule(ModuleName, FileName)
            .DefineType($"{ModuleName}.{ClassName}", ClassAttributes, typeof(object), new Type[] { typeof(IModule) });

         var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("OnInitialized", InterfaceMethodAttributes, CallingConventions.Standard, typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(IContainerProvider) });
         methodBuilder.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "containerProvider");

         var ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
         ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
         ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

         methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("RegisterTypes", InterfaceMethodAttributes, CallingConventions.Standard, typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(IContainerRegistry) });
         methodBuilder.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "containerRegistry");

         ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
         ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
         ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

         typeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

         typeBuilder.CreateType();

         assemblyBuilder.Save(FileName);
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that the generated IL code is slightly different. It looks as follows:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit BasicModule.BasicModule
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
       implements [Prism]Prism.Modularity.IModule
{
} // end of class BasicModule.BasicModule


.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void  .ctor() cil managed
{
  // Code size       7 (0x7)
  .maxstack  2
  IL_0000:  ldarg.0
  IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  ret
} // end of method BasicModule::.ctor


.method public hidebysig newslot virtual final 
        instance void  OnInitialized(class [Prism]Prism.Ioc.IContainerProvider containerProvider) cil managed
{
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  0
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method BasicModule::OnInitialized


.method public hidebysig newslot virtual final 
        instance void  RegisterTypes(class [Prism]Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistry containerRegistry) cil managed
{
  // Code size       2 (0x2)
  .maxstack  0
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ret
} // end of method BasicModule::RegisterTypes
```

First, the generated constructor contains a different `.maxstack`, 2 instead of 8, and there is a `nop` opcode missing. Second, both `OnInitialized` and `RegisterTypes` have a `.maxstack` of 0 instead of 8.

How do I need to change my C# code so that the generated assembly contains the exact same IL code as the original?

**EDIT**:

The reason this *seems* like an issue is that if I open the generated assembly in ILSpy, I'm getting the following output:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
    instance void .ctor () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2070
    // Header size: 12
    // Code size: 7 (0x7)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init /* Signature type sequence must have at least one element. */ (
    )

    /* 0x0000207C 02                 */ IL_0000: ldarg.0
    /* 0x0000207D 280100000A         */ IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    /* 0x00002082 2A                 */ IL_0006: ret
} // end of method BasicModule::.ctor


.method public final hidebysig newslot virtual 
    instance void OnInitialized (
        class [Prism]Prism.Ioc.IContainerProvider containerProvider
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Header size: 12
    // Code size: 2 (0x2)
    .maxstack 0
    .locals init /* Signature type sequence must have at least one element. */ (
    )

    /* 0x0000205C 00                 */ IL_0000: nop
    /* 0x0000205D 2A                 */ IL_0001: ret
} // end of method BasicModule::OnInitialized


.method public final hidebysig newslot virtual 
    instance void RegisterTypes (
        class [Prism]Prism.Ioc.IContainerRegistry containerRegistry
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2060
    // Header size: 12
    // Code size: 2 (0x2)
    .maxstack 0
    .locals init /* Signature type sequence must have at least one element. */ (
    )

    /* 0x0000206C 00                 */ IL_0000: nop
    /* 0x0000206D 2A                 */ IL_0001: ret
} // end of method BasicModule::RegisterTypes
```

`.locals init /* Signature type sequence must have at least one element.` does sound to me like things are not as they should be.

Comment: Generate the constructor yourself if you do no like the default constructor. A few details about the maxstack can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656409. Can you elaborate why do you think you have to change both details? The provided code should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question. When viewing the generated assembly in ILSpy it seems like something is not as it should be.

Comment: Q: How do I need to change my C# code so that the generated assembly contains the exact same IL code as the original?  A: As Bindy explained below, you probably *CAN'T*. 
 "System.Reflection.Emit" dynamically-generated code will not be "identical".  "Similar"? Perhaps.  "Good enough"?  Probably.  "Identical"?  No.  ALSO: What are you really trying to accomplish? This sounds like it might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  Perhaps (as Bindy suggested), [Code Generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) might be a better solution.

Comment: @paulsm4 Considering that the code might never be identical, the whole thing is then coming down to the question why ILSpy is stating `Signature type sequence must have at least one element` (as shown in the edit). When switching to C# instead of IL in ILSpy, this is considered to be an error. I would assume that it is possible to generate an assembly that ILSpy considers to be valid, even with `System.Reflection.Emit`.

Comment: Sigh...  I'm still curious why you're doing this? Q: Just "experimenting" out of "curiosity"? Or do you have a specific goal ... which might be better served by a different solution?  Q: Have you tried executing the generated code?  Does it work? ANYWAY: I assume that the original ".maxstack" question is moot.  SUGGESTION: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55508903/421195.  ALSO: Please consider "upvoting" and/or "accepting" Blindy's reply.

Comment: Can you check with peverify if the generated assembly contains actual errors? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/peverify-exe-peverify-tool

Comment: @paulsm4 Eventually, it's about testing a program that relies on `System.Reflection.Metadata` to extract information from .NET assemblies. To test that, I need several variations of various assemblies. Generating assemblies programmatically seems like a good way to create the variations that I need.

Answer (score 2):

> [...] `System.Reflection.Emit`. The assembly should be identical to the assembly that results from compiling

You can stop there, your assumption is invalid. You can in fact not generate code similar to the modern C# compiler using `Reflection.Emit`.

There is a better alternative, `Mono.Cecil`, which will get you further, but you're still dealing with a technological dead-end. What you should be using for this, and what people use for this kind of thing a lot, are [source generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview).

Comment: Is your statement also valid when working with .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Comment: Which statement in particular are you asking about?

Comment: I mean >You can in fact not generate code similar to the modern C# compiler using Reflection.Emit.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. `Reflection.Emit` is .Net 1.0, nothing more.

Comment: I can't find any documentation that points out that limitation. Where did you get that information from?

Comment: From having used it.